# particular integral in partial differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Solve the partial differential equation
$$\left[D^2+{D^\prime}^2\right]z=\cos mx\cdot\cos ny.$$

I have a problem in finding particular integral where $\displaystyle\frac\partial{\partial x}=D$ and $\displaystyle\frac\partial{\partial y}=D^\prime$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:-*$\frac{1}{2}(2cosmx.cosny)=\frac{1}{2}[cos(mx-ny)+cos(mx+ny)]$

and $\frac{1}{D^2+D'^2} cos(mx+ny)=\frac{cos(mx+ny)}{-m^2-n^2}$

Comment: that i know...i ve gone through that but my answer is not matching

Comment: i pray u can u plz wite down this in any page and clyk d image in ur cell phone.. then post it.......... im having trouble

Comment: i mean the full solution

Comment: @stackface337..you show your work in order to identify others tyat where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial y^2}=\cos (mx)\,\cos (ny)\qquad (1)$$
The particular solution of (1) is sought in the form
$$z=A\,\cos (mx)\,\cos (ny)$$
Substitution this in (1) yields
$$-A\, {{n}^{2}} \cos{\left( m x\right) } \cos{\left( n y\right) }-A\, {{m}^{2}} \cos{\left( m x\right) } \cos{\left( n y\right) }=\cos{\left( m x\right) } \cos{\left( n y\right) }$$
Then $$A=-\frac{1}{n^2+m^2},$$
$$z_p=-\frac{\cos (mx)\cdot\cos (ny)}{n^2+m^2}$$